# Jest module not defined

Tags: node.js, jestjs, github-actions

I'm writing my first package and I just converted it to be TypeScript compatible, but this somehow affected my GitHub workflow. When I run my tests using Jest locally, they work just fine. When my tests are run on GitHub, it succeeds for `10.x`, but not `12.x` or `14.x`, giving me the following error:

```
(node:2397) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at file:///home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS/jest.config.js:1:1
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:146:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:126:32)
    at async readConfig (/home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:217:18)
    at async readConfigs (/home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:406:26)
    at async runCLI (/home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:230:59)
    at async Object.run (/home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:163:37)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
enhancedmath@2.0.0 test /home/runner/work/enhancedMathJS/enhancedMathJS
jest
```

#### File *jest.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.spec.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  coverageDirectory: './test-reports',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', 'src/database', 'src/test', 'src/types'],
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
  globals: { 'ts-jest': { diagnostics: false } },
};
```

#### Workflow

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm test
```

I don't understand what the problem is, since everything works locally, but not for every version of Node.js on GitHub.

If you want to check out the files and errors for yourself, you can find my repository [here](https://github.com/MoutPessemier/enhancedMathJS).

Comment: Thought 1: if you have ESM code, it has to be a real ESM, not "a mix of ESM and legacy code that also tries to use node's CJS `module` namespace". And if you don't have mixed code (but it sure sounds like you do), thought 2: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules, point 2?

Comment: No, I still get module not defined as the main error, and with version `12.x`, it's still considered experimental

Comment: it was, which is why you need that runtime flag passed through if you're still on the previous LTS version (the current LTS is 14). That said: start reducing until you have a single file left that still generates that error: now you have a [mcve] to show folks here, so they can meaningfully comment on why. Without code, there's just too many details missing.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I got it working by installing `ts-node` and updating my `jest.config.js` file to a `jest.config.ts` file:

`npm i --save-dev ts-node`

#### Jest config

```js
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.spec.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', 'src/database', 'src/test', 'src/types'],
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
  globals: { 'ts-jest': { diagnostics: false } },
  transform: {},
};
```

Comment: A simple rename fixed me!!! Thank you

Comment: `globals: { 'ts-jest': { diagnostics: false } },` worked for me, but received the following warning `ts-jest[ts-jest-transformer] (WARN) Define ts-jest config under globals is deprecated. Please do
transform: {<transform_regex>: ['ts-jest', { /* ts-jest config goes here in Jest */ }]},`. I removed the globals key and added `diagnostics: false,` to transform, but that didn't work.

`transform: {'^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest',{tsconfig: __dirname + '/tsconfig.json',diagnostics: false}]}`

Comment: Both the rename to *.ts and the `npm i --D ts-node` were necessary in my case. After these two changes, using the default jest config file that comes with `npx ts-jest config:init` mostly worked.

Answer (score 49):

I use [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) in my project. And config `{ type: "module" }` in file *package.json*. So just change `module.exports =` to `export default`.

Comment: +1,

The other answer is suggesting you might need `ts-node` when very likely all you are doing is having a commonjs VS esModules type of issue

Comment: Any way to achieve this with an existing [esbuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild) setup?

Answer (score 36):

I got the very similar error `ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope` when running Jest in ESM context.

This did the trick for me:

In `jest.config.js`, change

```
module.exports = {
  /* config here */
}
```

to

```
export default {
  /* config here */ 
}
```

Most tutorials as well as Jest's config scaffolding make the config a CJS module which will lead to the above error if you use it in ESM context.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. Thanks.